# AWS AMI import of HyperV Virtual Machine on LVM extended partition on Two drives

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, linux-networking, aws-cli, aws-systems-manager

I am having a problem today while importing a hyper-V vm to AWS AMI. 
Actually my VM has 2 Harddisk and both of them LVM set and use as single LVG expended volume on both drives. now when i am importing first disk as ami. it give me an error saying  "Logical volume group activation failed" Please guide if this is actually happening due to multiple LVM expended drives or i am doing something wrong.

I am using normal process.
1- exporting hyperv VM.
2- upload into S3
3- finally import with CLI command (which end up in above error)

any guide will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Yousuf

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding on this. Your disk is not AMI, it's storage actually. AMI is just configuration that EC2 service will use to launch your instance.

> An AMI includes the following:
>
> One or more EBS snapshots, or, for instance-store-backed AMIs, a
>   template for the root volume of the instance (for example, an
>   operating system, an application server, and applications).
>
> Launch permissions that control which AWS accounts can use the AMI to
>   launch instances.
>
> A block device mapping that specifies the volumes to attach to the
>   instance when it's launched.

You may want to read more about Instance Store-Backed Linux AMI.

In my opinion, your migration methods from your on-preemies to cloud is not proper. You should consider to only migrate data to cloud and spend time to initialize a new OS on there.

Comment: Thank you for you comments, actually Data migration was one of the option in mind but we had like around 100 websites and all of them are custom configured. like via CLI no WHM is being use. therefore migration would take a lot of time and to avoid that i though i would have used AMI. Please correct me if i am wrong with understanding

Comment: I think the following link is a good starting point. Let give a try, I look forward to your comment here. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/